# Не запускается код. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

Tags: python, tkinter

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/egor-lyadsky/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 1, in 
from tkinter import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку у Вас вывод указывает на исполнение в *NIX системе, осмелюсь предположить, что используется Debian подобный дистрибутив. В таком случае просто запустите

```
sudo apt install python3-tk
```

Если у Вас Arch, то

```
sudo pacman -S python3-tk
```

В иных случаях смотрите менеджер пакетов своей OS.

Comment: ничего не поменялось

Comment: У pycharm вроде свой virtualenv.

Comment: В python tkinter предустановлен, вероятно, вы могли его случайно удалить. В таком случае, вам нужно пересоздать ваше виртуальное окружение.

Comment: Ещё, как вариант, pip install tkintertable

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в папку .loсal (находится в домашней папке(скорее всего это скрытая папка, нажмите CTRL + H)), там найдите пакет tkinter (или что то другое похожее на  tkinter, смотря что вы установили). И затем скопируйте его в папку с проектом (лучше в virtualvenv, если он у Вас есть). Должно помочь

Answer (score -1):

Если у вас Windows, то может быть, у вас по-другому называется библиотека:

```bsh
pip install tkinter
```

Потом замените `import tkinter` на `import TKinter`.

Если не поможет, то замените на `import Tkinter`.

Если нету pip:

```bsh
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Надеюсь, поможет!

Comment: Это всё не работает

Comment: Из вопроса видно, что не Windows

Answer (score -1):

Ответ для Linux (похоже, но изменено):

```bsh
pip3 install tkinter
```

Потом замените import tkinter на import TKinter.

Если не поможет, то замените на import Tkinter.

Если нету pip:

`sudo apt -y install python3-pip`

Если ничего из этого не сработает, то не знаю.

Comment: Это всё тоже не работает, потому что на PyPI в принципе не существует пакета tkinter и никогда не существовало